# Implementing merge sort in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I don't know what's wrong here. can anyone help me do merge sort in python3.Please ,where did i go wrong....?

```
def merge_help(a,b):
    c=[]
    j=0
    i=0
    while(i<len(a) and j<len(b)):
        if(a[i]>=b[j]):
            c.append(b[j])
            j+=1
        elif(a[i]<=b[j]):
            c.append(a[i])
            i+=1
    while(j<len(b)):
        c.append(b[j])
        j+=1
    while(i<len(a)):
        c.append(a[i])
        i+=1
    return c
    def merge(a):
    if(len(a)>1):
        mid =len(a)//2
        l=a[:mid]
        r=a[mid:]
        merge(l)
        merge(r)
        merge_help(l,r)
    print(a)
```

`merge([12,11,13,5,6,7])` doesn't work.... no errors but same list is returned back every recursive step

Comment: Your code will be much easier to read and interpret if you use the correct indentation in the question.
Sorry, I'm unable to understand the query. Can you explain what you mean by merge sort & what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing the output of merge_help, so you are not actually changing the values in the 'a' list.

You are also attempting to do this in-place, which is not possible with merge sort.

In your merge function, do this:

```
def merge(a):
    if(len(a) > 1):
        # Divide the list in two
        mid = len(a)//2
        left_unsorted = a[:mid]
        right_unsorted = a[mid:]

        # Sort both halves
        left_sorted = merge(left_unsorted)
        right_sorted = merge(right_unsorted)

        # Merge the two sorted lists
        a_sorted = merge_help(left_sorted, right_sorted)
    else:
        a_sorted = a.copy()
    return a_sorted
```

*Note:* this does not sort the passed list; it only returns a sorted version. So if you call it with orig_list, orig_list will be unchanged at the end.

Comment: Where are you dividing the array into sub arrays??And this gives same o/p

Comment: The 'left' and 'right' sub arrays are sorted versions of the first half and second half of the original 'a' array. I'll add comments in the above code to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks i understood my problem

Answer (score -1):

You append the fields from a and b to c, but in the end you print a.
Maybe this is the problem.

Array a is never edited

Comment: The indenting makes this confusing, but the 'a' that is printed is the sole argument to the merge function, not the 'a' in the merge_help function.

Comment: I tried
In last 4 lines
return merge_help(l,r)
a=[12,11,13,5,6,7]
b=merge(a)
print(b)
The answer was:[5, 6, 7, 12, 11, 13] Please help!!!